# Laravel hook into Eloquent Query Builder Collection after query?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is there an elegant or proper way to extend `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent` to modify the Collection that is returned?

For example, I have some code which needs to take some of the data for each model, and create a new property by looping through the data.

I prefer not to use a dynamic attribute for this, but maybe that's the cleanest way, as opposed to looping on the result after `->get()` is called and having to do this in a Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using as [custom collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections#custom-collections).

With that you can modify the collection, enrich it with your own methods and so on.